# Processing each of the second and further arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a bash scripts accepting 1 one more arguments. I want to handle each of the second and further arguments separately. Here is my attempt:

```
SECOND_PLUS_ARGS="${@:2}"

for arg in "${SECOND_PLUS_ARGS[@]}"; do
    echo "arg = $arg"
done
```

Running it as `./script.sh 1 2 3 4` the following output is printed:

```
$ ./script.sh 1 2 3 4                                                                                                                                                                        
arg = 2 3 4
```

**I expected:**

```
$ ./script.sh 1 2 3 4                                                                                                                                                                        
arg = 2
arg = 3
arg = 4
```

Is there a way to fix the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make much sense to create `SECOND_PLUS_ARGS` as scalar and then use it as array. Create it as array:

```
SECOND_PLUS_ARGS=("${@:2}")
```